# Estimote iOs SDK error

Tags: ios, ibeacon

I added the Estimote SDK to the project and when I try to run it in a device I have the following error:

> ld: framework not found Metal for architecture armv7
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

To do it I followed the manual installation from here: https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-SDK

I'm using XCODE 5.1

I hope somebody can help me,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found after trying a lot of different things was to update to iOS 8